# PHP Eclipse Configuration

Tags: php, eclipse

I want to use Eclipse IDE for PHP. I'm new to Eclipse and also to PHP. I installed Eclipse, PHP and Apache. For Eclipse i installed Zend debugger also. I configured Eclipse and set the paths to PHP exe. But when i try to run small PHP code as a script it shows a error message as bellow.

Error launching 'test'

The session could not be started.
In order to generate debug information, please make sure that the debugger is properly configured as a php.ini directive.

What shall i do for this. Please tell me how to configure Eclipse.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Debug Configuration -> Installed PHP -> Add (or Edit)

Make sure that the Debugger is set correctly (in my case it should be Xdebug)